# Homebrew switch formula if name is not matching

Tags: lua, homebrew

I'm trying to switch to an older `lua` package. When doing `brew search lua` I get:

```
lua ✔                                        
lua@5.1 ✔
```

And I have both installed. But when I do `brew switch lua 5.1` I get

```
brew switch lua 5.1                
Error: lua does not have a version "5.1" in the Cellar.
lua installed versions: 5.3.4_3
```

One package seemed to be called `lua` while the other is `lua@5.1`. How do I switch lua here?

My problem is when I run `luarocks install ...` it installs using v5.3 and I want it to use 5.1

Comment: Did you try literally `lua@5.1`?

Comment: The problem is `luarocks` installs with `lua` 5.3 ...